# React-Native: How to run device shake code without prompting Expo/debugging menu

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to create a react native app that uses a shake gesture event listener. When I shake the device it will bring up Expo or the regular react-native runtime menu and trigger the event. However, this is really time consuming to close that menu per shake especially since the app centers around the shaking of the phone to trigger the event, and it interrupts the app. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is what found:

`adb shell input keyevent 82`

Souce: [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/87hvq5/shake_the_phone_to_update_is_there_a_better_way/dwd5x4a).